# How do you add a class in Android Studio 1.1.0?

Tags: android, testing

I'm trying to add a class in a java directory in Android Studio 1.1.0 and I don't' have the options. The only options that I have are file director or html file.  How do I add a class?

[image]

Comment: I think this is your problem: [Why Android Studio doesn't allow me to create Java Classes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20588040/why-android-studio-doesnt-allow-me-to-create-java-classes)

Comment: It looks like you are trying to work with a sourceset that is not part of the current build variant. Click on the Build Variant view (docked on the left edge by default) and make sure that it is set to the build variant you want to be working on.