# Can`t create java.class or java package in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio

I can't create Java class or Java package in Android Studio. 
I googled a lot, but no one has the answer for my problem....
Am I in the wrong view or something?

[image]

Comment: did you check this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20588040/why-android-studio-doesnt-allow-me-to-create-java-classes

Comment: yes.... at the picture you see i can`t click "mark directory as"

Comment: solved->delete at the /users the android folder. Reinstalled.

Comment: Or you may just New->File and then type FileName.`java` as a suffix of the file