# Create New Java Class not accepting the options

Tags: android, android-activity

In android studio when I am creating a new java class , after entering the class name if I am clicking on 'ok' it is not working... It is neither showing any error nor it is creating the class. The cancel button is working fine. 
(I am just starting with Android development)
Thank You.

Comment: Have you updated your Android Studio to the latest version ?

Comment: Following link may help you, plz go through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20588040/why-android-studio-doesnt-allow-me-to-create-java-classes

Comment: It's not like it is not showing the create class option. It is showing it but not actually creating any java class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug of the latest android update (i.e. 3.1.2)
Try doing first go to Files -> invalidate caches / restart and then a dialog  will pop up click on invalidate and restart 
or if this doesn't works right click on the package you want to make class in and go to show in explorer and make a new text file there with extension .java