# Convert an existing Flutter Kotlin project to Flutter Java project

Tags: java, android, kotlin, flutter

I created a Flutter project using default values, which are Kotlin for Android and Swift for iOS. Halfway through the project I needed to integrate a 3rd party Android SDK that requires Java. Can I convert a Flutter project to Java for Android after creation?

I know I will need yo use Platform Channels to integrate native code with my Flutter app, this is not my concern.

Comment: Kotlin can work with Java libraries.

Comment: In Android studio you can convert java into kotlin. I've never looked for it, but maybe there is an option to do it the other way. Look for it under "Refactor"

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I had the same problem, for me this solution works.

1. Move folder com.example.test_app (any name you have) from android/app/src/main/kotlin -> android/app/src/main/java
2. Replace MainActivity.kt with Java version, or copy down here

   ```
   package com.example.test_app;

   import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
   import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity;
   import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine;
   import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;

   public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
    @Override
    public void configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine);
    }
   }
   ```
3. Remove following code android/app/build.grandle

   ```
   ...
   apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
   ...
   sourceSets {
       main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
   }
   ```
4. In the same place replace following:

   ```
   dependencies {
       implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
       testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
       androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0'
       androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
   }
   ```

   to

   ```
   dependencies {
       testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
       androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
       androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
   }
   ```

Comment: I've already done that, but always read kotlin file ```Couldn't read file LocalFile: 'xxxx.kt' even though it exists. Please verify that this file has read permission and try again.```

Comment: In my case, I've already done all the very same steps, but I got `/MainActivity.java:13: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override` (cannot override `configureFlutterEngine`) :(

Comment: @daveoncode These imports worked for me. import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity;
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;

Comment: don't forget to change "test_app" from the import line to the name of your app

Answer (score 18):

By default flutter template supports writing Android code using Kotlin, or iOS code using Swift. To use Java or Objective-C, use the -i and/or -a flags:

In a terminal run: `flutter create -i objc -a java your_project_name`.

If you wanna change your existing app **platform language choice**, as a workaround you can **delete the android/ directory** and run **`flutter create -a java`** to get the directory re-created for the new language choice (same for ios/ and Swift).
You need to re-apply custom changes though.

Comment: flutter create -a java didn't work properly, it returned "No option specified for the output directory" , I advice all not to delete android directory , however renaming it or move it somewhere else for backups. until you make sure the new directory is created successfully .

Comment: you need to specify your project's directory. if you are inside the dir just ad a '.' at the end: `flutter create -a java .`

Answer (score 17):

run `flutter create -a java .` inside your project directory

> flutter create: If run on a project that already exists, this will
>   repair the project, recreating any files that are missing.

delete the `kotlin` directory in `android/src/main` if it only consists of the generated example code

Answer (score 17):

If you are creating a new project from cmd:

`flutter create -i objc -a java project_name`

Note: -a means android flag and -i means ios flag. If you want just for java, you can remove `-i objc`

If you want to convert an existing project:

`flutter create -a java .`

**There is a dot at the end of the above line, when converting an existing project**

Comment: In my case I have to add the organization flag `--org you-app-package(com.example)`

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to follow up with this, as I had to change the default language in my Flutter project from Kotlin to Java today, and ran into a little pain point, where I found that running `flutter create -i swift -a java .` in my project directory worked, but was causing my project name to change based on whatever directory it was in, and if that directory name was the last value of my "package name" (ie: com.flutter.app and the directory was "app"), this was then throwing a `D8: Program type already present:` error when compiling.

This is due to the MainActivity of the original Kotlin src.   What I discovered is that I had to *(after checking out my source code into this "app" folder that I wanted to use in the package name)*, first delete this existing `android/app/src/main/kotlin` folder AND THEN run the `flutter create -i swift -a java .` command.

Note that I didn't have any unique code added to the Kotlin folder, so removal of this folder wasn't a concern.

Hope this helps anyone else experiencing a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case after trying to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63197495/7199821) then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58602076/7199821), you found out that you cannot generate java class, suggestion and navigate declaration doesn't appear, etc.,

right click java folder, Mark Directory as > Source root. Then, edit your java class by open new android studio window by choose `android` directory

reference : [Why Android Studio doesn't allow me to create Java Classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20588040/why-android-studio-doesnt-allow-me-to-create-java-classes)

Answer (score 0):

I am on Kotlin /Flutter too.

With the latest Firebase Flutter rewrite, most of the kt files are no longer needed. Switch to v2 embedding, and it wont matter you are using Kotlin...

https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/migration/