# Migrating flutter kotlin to flutter java

Tags: java, android, flutter, kotlin

I have an app almost completed but I have encountered a problem. I need to add native code to my app, I am using method channel to implement native code. The problem is I want java as my native language. But unfortunately, I created the project with Kotlin as the native one. I need to migrate my file to java.

I tried:

1. Changing the com.example files from kotlin to java directory and changing dependencies accordingly. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/58602076/14555109)
2. Tried [Flutter create -a -java .] It creates an entire flutter file inside the directory specified.

Both did not work out for me. Can anyone help me with other methods to migrate the file?