# Flutter app stuck on black screen after integrating native android sdk

Tags: java, android, flutter, android-manifest, android-native-library

I have a Flutter app on version 2.2.3 into which I recently integrated a native SDK using the Platform channel method. For some reason after doing this, my Flutter app started **showing a black screen** whenever I run it either on the emulator or on an actual device. The app gets stuck on the black screen and does not proceed to showing the Home Screen. Here is my code for the main file:

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  InAppPurchaseAndroidPlatformAddition.enablePendingPurchases();

  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final Future<FirebaseApp> _initialization = Firebase.initializeApp();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
        [DeviceOrientation.portraitUp, DeviceOrientation.portraitDown]);
    print('Inside main.dart build method');
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: _initialization,
        builder: (context2, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            NetworkErr();
            return Container();
          } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            return MultiProvider(
              providers: [
                ChangeNotifierProvider(
                  create: (ctx) => ClueList(),
                ),
                ChangeNotifierProvider(
                  create: (ctx) => Score(),
                ),
                ChangeNotifierProvider(
                  create: (ctx) => Auth(),
                ),
                ChangeNotifierProvider(
                  create: (ctx) => Badges(),
                ),
              ],
              child: MaterialApp(
                theme: ThemeData(
                    primarySwatch: Colors.teal,
                    // primaryColor: Color.fromARGB(150, 35, 152, 159,),
                    primaryColorLight: Color.fromARGB(
                      80,
                      35,
                      152,
                      159,
                    ),
                    accentColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 185, 36),
                    textTheme: ThemeData.light().textTheme.copyWith(
                            bodyText2: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: 'Happy School',
                          fontSize: 20,
                        ))),
                home: HomeScreen(),
```

In the MainActivity.java file I have integrated the native sdk wherein I make a call to retrieve ads from Yodo1 MAS Below is the code from MainActivity.java file.

```
package com.example.xxxxx;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import com.yodo1.mas.Yodo1Mas;
import com.yodo1.mas.error.Yodo1MasError;
import com.yodo1.mas.event.Yodo1MasAdEvent;

import io.flutter.app.FlutterActivity;
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodCall;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodCall;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel.Result;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;

public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {

   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        System.out.println("before Calling MAS Get Instance");

        Yodo1Mas.getInstance().init(this, "xxxxxxxxx", new Yodo1Mas.InitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMasInitSuccessful() {
             System.out.println("MAS Init Successful");

            }

            @Override
            public void onMasInitFailed(@NonNull Yodo1MasError error) {

            }
        });
        new MethodChannel(getFlutterView(), "com.examples.xxxxxx/yodo1").setMethodCallHandler(
            new MethodCallHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onMethodCall(MethodCall call, Result result) {
                    if (call.method.equals("getBannerAd")) {
                        System.out.println("RADHA LOading Banner Ad");
                        getBannerAd();

                    }
                }
            }
        );
        
    }

    private void getBannerAd() {

        int align = Yodo1Mas.BannerTop | Yodo1Mas.BannerHorizontalCenter;

        boolean isLoaded = Yodo1Mas.getInstance().isBannerAdLoaded();
        
            if (isLoaded) {
            Yodo1Mas.getInstance().showBannerAd(MainActivity.this, align);
            Yodo1Mas.getInstance().setBannerListener(new Yodo1Mas.BannerListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdOpened(@NonNull Yodo1MasAdEvent event) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdError(@NonNull Yodo1MasAdEvent event, @NonNull Yodo1MasError error) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAdClosed(@NonNull Yodo1MasAdEvent event) {

            }
        }    
        );
    }
    }
}
```

This is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.xxxxx">
    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />    

    <application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="false"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
           
                         
  
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
          
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"/> 
       
            <!-- <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
            android:value="@string/app_id" /> -->
        <!-- <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" /> -->
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I also tried the following:

1. I ran `flutter pub cache repair`
2. My original project was a Flutter + Kotlin project. Since the code to integrate the native sdk was only available in Java, I converted the project into a Java project by moving the folder structure from src/main/kotlin to src/main/java as explained here :
   [Convert an existing Flutter Kotlin project to Flutter Java project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58579774/convert-an-existing-flutter-kotlin-project-to-flutter-java-project)

I've been stuck with this for over 3 days now. I searched almost all the solutions I found on SOF for the black screen but to no avail. If you have any other suggestions please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: did you figure out how to fix it?

Comment: Hey Dani. Yes ... I finally had to move to a new project. Migrated all the files part by part to a new project and got the basic app to start working. It was probably just something that had got messed up in the existing project when I upgraded Flutter to 2.2.x. A bit of a pain to do but it finally worked and I could at least put a new version to Play Store

Comment: and how did you manage the rewarded videos? I can show everything but I don't know how to listen to onAdverRewardEarned in order to detect from Flutter if the user watched the video or not