# Custom Java class not found by MainActivity in AndroidStudio

Tags: java, android-studio

I started a new project. Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20588040/why-android-studio-doesnt-allow-me-to-create-java-classes), I set `app/src` as "Sources Root". Then I made a new class `CustomClass` under `app/src`. I want to construct an instance of this class for the app to access and run, so I tried to do this in MainActivity (in `/app/src/main/java/com.example.testapp`):

```
import CustomClass;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    CustomClass newObject = new CustomClass();
    ...
}
```

but the first line gives a "Cannot resolve symbol 'CustomClass' " error.

If I make another class in `/app/src`, it can import CustomClass without an issue. It seems like MainActivity doesn't know where to look for the new class. How can I tell it to import the new class?

Comment: You should import the class by it's full package name. Try- import com.example.testapp.CustomClass. Also, Importing is not required at all if your MainActivity is in the same package as the CustomClass.

Comment: Is there a way to find the package that a class belongs to? `import com.example.testapp.CustomClass` gives the same error. And calling the class directly without importing gives the same error.

Comment: Yes, every file in java declares what package it belongs to. The first line in the file reads: `package your.package.name;`